# Extract colors from css file using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, search, preg-match, extract

I am trying to extract colors from a css file using php.
These colors may be:

1. normal colors (color: #xxxxxx;)
2. background colors (background: #xxxxxx; / background: ... #xxxxxx ...;)
3. background gradients (background-image: linear-gradient(top, #xxxxxx, #xxxxxx);
4. sometimes colors may be 3 chars (eg: #fff)

I tried preg match to return words starting with #

```
preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(#\w+\b)/', $css_text, $matches)
```

...but it also returns DIV Ids (#header etc.)

Moving forward, I also wish our code to return a multidimensional array with not only color codes but also line number on which it was found.

Please help! :)

---------- EDIT: Question SOLVED ----------

Thankyou all for you answers, I kind of combined everybody's answers.
As i wanted to keep regex to minimum, **this is what i used as final working code**:

```
$css = file_get_contents("style.css");

$token = strtok($css, "{}");
$css_parts = array();
while ($token !== false) {
    $css_parts[] = trim($token);
    $token = strtok("{}");
}

$flag = false; $properties = "";
    foreach($css_parts as $part) {
    if($flag) { $properties .= " ".trim($part); }
    $flag = !$flag;
}
$properties = strtoupper(str_replace(array(":",",",";","(",")")," ",$properties));

$colors = array();
preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(#\w+\b)/',$properties,$colors);
$colors = array_unique($colors[0]);

print_r($colors);
```

Comment: if you expand your expression to include the colon, that should take care of the div ids

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I thought about it, but sometimes there may be one or more space between ":" and "#" - also, i think it wont cover case 2 and 3 of my requirements list, correct me if i am wrong - i am not not a pro at writing these expressions!

Comment: i've actually just been reading on this. you can use ": *#" to tell it to handle any number of spaces between the colon and the #. asterisk means 0 to n times, a plus sign works if you know there will be at least one space

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Understood. But in case we have [background: url() #xxx;] or [background-image: linear-gradient(top, #xxxxxx, #xxxxxx] ??

Comment: By the way, don't you also need to find `rgba` colors...? For example - see end of line 38 of your css example output.

Comment: I don't think your code returns the line numbers also (as you said you would like it to do)...?

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll only accept 3 or 6 hexadecimal characters, I think this regular expression could be more accurate:

```
/(?!\b)((#[0-9abcdef]{3}|#[0-9abcdef]{6})\b)/
```

However, IDs with those characters will also be matched. Thus, I don't suggest using regular expressions to solve this problem.

Comment: I understand your suggestion of not using regex, can you refer to 'Edit 1' in questions and push me ahead on this one?

Comment: It's almost the same, you only have to add an OR for the colon and the semicolon at the end: `/(?!\b)((#[0-9abcdef]{3}|#[0-9abcdef]{6})(\b|;|,))/`

Comment: Actually that wont work because colors can be within shorthands and proprietary selectors. Also, you need to check for 6 first because otherwise it won't match.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this with a three pronged approach fairly easily as long as you assume there are no curly brackets within selectors (usually a good assumption).

Step 1: grab contents inside of {}

```
preg_match( '/\{([^\}]*)\}/gi' , $css_text , $lines );
```

Step 2: grab colors

```
$colors = array();
$i = sizeof($lines);

while( $i-- ) {
    preg_match( '/(#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3})/' , $line[$i] , $matches );
    $colors += $matches; //combine the arrays
}
```

Comment: also, sometimes it's good to go ahead and strip whitespace to ensure it doesn't mess up and pattern matching. E.g. `preg_replace('/\s/g','',$css_text);`

Comment: Thanks, looks really good! But I am getting "Unknown modifier 'g'" error with preg_match

Comment: just change it to preg_match_all and remove the g, I forgot that PHP doesn't allow the g modifier because they separate global into a separate function

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code not using regex (it loops over lines and characters), but which gets the job done.  It produces an associative array where a key is a hex color code, and a value is an array of line numbers where the color key was found.  (Can be modified to include rgba color keys as well).

```
$lst_lines = array(
   35 => "color: #000;text-decoration: none;",
   36 => "font-size: 2.5em;",
   37 => "margin-top: 5px;line-height: 60px;height: 60px;float: right;border-radius: 5px;box-  shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #872424, inset 0px 2px 0px 0px #F79494, inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #E78484;background: #A74444;background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A74444, #C76464);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A74444, #C76464);background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A74444, #C76464);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A74444, #C76464);background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A74444, #C76464);text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);",
   38 => "color: #1D1D1D;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 1.1em;letter-spacing: -1px;text-decoration: none;color: #fff;opacity: 0.6;filter:alpha(opacity='50');",
);

// returns color in $str_line at position $int_pos
function findColor($int_pos, $str_line) {
    $str_temp = substr($str_line, $int_pos, 6);
    $lst_temp = str_split($str_temp);
    $lst_end = array(',', ';', ')', '}', ' ');
    $hex_color = '#';
    foreach ($lst_temp as $i => $c) {
        if (!in_array($c, $lst_end) && ($i < 6)) $hex_color .= $c;
        else break;
    }
    return $hex_color;
}

$arr_colors = array();    // This is the output array
foreach ($lst_lines as $int_no => $str_line) {
    $lst_chars = str_split($str_line);
    foreach ($lst_chars as $i => $c) {
        if ($c == '#') {
            $hex_col = findColor($i+1, $str_line);
            $arr_colors[$hex_col][] = $int_no;
        }
    }
}
```